# Django Admin custom change form saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to apply a quite different graphic template for a tab in my change_form, so I tried using an inline with a custom template to fill this whole tab.

However, now, whenever I try to save some data on my change_form, it doesn't work : no error is thrown, but the data is not saved. I tried to change things in the save_model() method and the clean() method, but to no avail.

Here is the code :
model.py :

```
class Session (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    difficulty_rate = models.IntegerField(_('difficulty_rate'), default=0)
    effort_rate = models.IntegerField(_('effort_rate'), default=0)
    muscular_rate = models.IntegerField(_('muscular_rate'), default=0)
```

admin.py :

```
class Sessionform(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'difficulty_rate': TextInput(attrs={
                                    'data-slider-ticks':'[0,1,2,3,4,5]',
                                    'data-slider-ticks-labels':_('["none", "", "","","","very hard"]'),
                                    'data-slider-min':'0',
                                    'data-slider-max':'5',
                                    'data-slider-step':'1',}),
        'effort_rate': TextInput(attrs={
                                    'data-slider-ticks':'[0,1,2,3,4,5]',
                                    'data-slider-ticks-labels':_('["none", "", "","","","very hard"]'),
                                    'data-slider-min':'0',
                                    'data-slider-max':'5',
                                    'data-slider-step':'1',}),
        'muscular_rate': TextInput(attrs={
                                    'data-slider-ticks':'[0,1,2,3,4,5]',
                                    'data-slider-ticks-labels':_('["none", "", "","","","very hard"]'),
                                    'data-slider-min':'0',
                                    'data-slider-max':'5',
                                    'data-slider-step':'1',}),

class SessionAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):

form = SessionForm
[...]

    suit_form_tabs = (('info', _('Informations')), ('model', _('Body model')))
    suit_form_includes = (
    ('bodyoppro/admin/session/information.html', 'top', 'info'),
    ('bodyoppro/admin/session/muscle_body.html', 'top', 'model'),
)
```

information.html :

```html
<div class="span3">
    <form method="post">
        <h4 align="center">Difficulty</h4>
        {{ adminform.form.difficulty_rate }}
        <h4 align="center">Effort</h4>
        {{ adminform.form.effort_rate }}
        <h4 align="center">Muscle</h4>
        {{ adminform.form.muscular_rate }}
    </form>
```

Could someone give me a hand ? Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Does it throw an error?  Does it run fine but not save?

Comment: Runs fine, but does not save any change.